# Error in Feature event receivers : Column does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user

Tags: content-type, column, feature, feature-receiver

I have created a custom list using custom content type.
on feature activation, adding items in the list.

but I'm facing error

```
Column 'LeaveStart' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.
```

I have check columns. they are available in the list

I'm getting error on this line

```
leaveItem["LeaveStart"] = leaveStart;
```

Here is my whole code

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite)
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    var leaveItemContentType = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes[leaveContentTypeName];
                    var leaveItemUsages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(leaveItemContentType);

                    var leaveEventContentType = site.RootWeb.ContentTypes[leavesCalenderContentTypeName];
                    var leaveEventUsages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(leaveEventContentType);

                    foreach (var leaveEventUsage in leaveEventUsages)
                    {
                        if (leaveEventUsage.IsUrlToList)
                        {
                            string url = leaveEventUsage.Url;

                            int lengthOfWebUrl = url.LastIndexOf("/Lists", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);

                            string webUrlForList = url.Substring(0, lengthOfWebUrl);

                            SPWeb webWithList = site.OpenWeb(webUrlForList);

                            SPList leaveEventList = webWithList.GetList(url);

                            SPQuery leavesEvantQuery = new SPQuery();
                            leavesEvantQuery.Query = "";
                            SPListItemCollection leaveEvents = leaveEventList.GetItems(leavesEvantQuery);
                            foreach (SPItem leaveEvent in leaveEvents)
                            {

                                var title = leaveEvent["Title"];
                                var employeeOnLeave = leaveEvent["EmployeeOnLeave"];
                                var departmentTitle = leaveEvent["DepartmentTitle"];
                                var leaveStart = leaveEvent["EventDate"];
                                var leaveEnd = leaveEvent["EndDate"];
                                var itemIdentifier = leaveEvent["ID"];

                                foreach (var leaveItemUsage in leaveItemUsages)
                                {

                                    if (leaveItemUsage.IsUrlToList)
                                    {
                                        string leaveItemUrl = leaveItemUsage.Url;

                                        int leaveItemLengthOfWebUrl = url.LastIndexOf("/Lists", System.StringComparison.Ordinal);

                                        string leaveItemWebUrlForList = url.Substring(0, lengthOfWebUrl);

                                        SPWeb leaveItemWebWithList = site.OpenWeb(webUrlForList);
                                        //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                        SPList leaveItemList = webWithList.GetList(url);

                                        SPItem leaveItem = leaveItemList.AddItem();

                                        leaveItem["Title"] = title;
                                        leaveItem["EmployeeOnLeave"] = employeeOnLeave;
                                        leaveItem["DepartmentTitle"] = departmentTitle;

                                         leaveItem["LeaveStart"] = leaveStart;

                                        leaveItem["LeaveEnd"] = leaveEnd;
                                        leaveItem["ItemIdentifier"] = itemIdentifier;
                                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                        leaveItem.Update();
                                    }
                                }

                            }



                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: is this column LeaveStart at your content type or your list ?

Comment: Column is available in content type add I'm using that content type in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you get the correct list `(item list)` and it's not the `event list` at this line

```
SPList leaveItemList = webWithList.GetList(url);
```

I noted that the previous fields  `EmployeeOnLeave` and `DepartmentTitle` are already created at both lists so the code raises the error when hitting at `LeaveStart` that actually not exist at `event list` but it exists at `item list` as you checked, so I think the list name has been set to `event list` not `item list`

Also, Make sure that `leaveItemContentType` at `var leaveItemUsages = SPContentTypeUsage.GetUsages(leaveItemContentType);` have the column `LeaveStart` and is the default content type.

Comment: thanks, actually I'm passing wrong list name and  wrong web.